# Building a RandomForest with caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

I was attempting to build a RandomForest model in caret following the steps [here](https://www.guru99.com/r-random-forest-tutorial.html).  Essentially, they set up the RandomForest, then the best mtry, then best maxnodes, then best number of trees.  These steps make sense, but wouldn't it be better to search the interaction of those three factors rather than one at a time?

Secondly, I understand performing a grid search for mtry and ntrees. But I do not know what to set the minimum number of nodes or maximum number of nodes at. Is it generally advisable leave the default nodesize as shown below?

```
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
mtrys<-seq(1,4,1)
ntrees<-c(250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 800, 1000, 2000)
combo_mtrTrees<-data.frame(expand.grid(mtrys, ntrees))
colnames(combo_mtrTrees)<-c('mtrys','ntrees')

tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(1: 4))
for (i in 1:length(ntrees)){
  ntree<-ntrees[i]
  set.seed(65)
  rf_maxtrees <- train(Species~.,
                       data = df,
                       method = "rf",
                       importance=TRUE,
                       metric = "Accuracy",
                       tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
                       trControl = trainControl( method = "cv",
                                                 number=5,
                                                 search = 'grid',
                                                 classProbs = TRUE,
                                                 savePredictions = "final"),
                       ntree = ntree
                       )
  Acc1<-rf_maxtrees$results$Accuracy[rf_maxtrees$results$mtry==1]
  Acc2<-rf_maxtrees$results$Accuracy[rf_maxtrees$results$mtry==2]
  Acc3<-rf_maxtrees$results$Accuracy[rf_maxtrees$results$mtry==3]
  Acc4<-rf_maxtrees$results$Accuracy[rf_maxtrees$results$mtry==4]
  combo_mtrTrees$Acc[combo_mtrTrees$mtrys==1 & combo_mtrTrees$ntrees==ntree]<-Acc1
  combo_mtrTrees$Acc[combo_mtrTrees$mtrys==2 & combo_mtrTrees$ntrees==ntree]<-Acc2
  combo_mtrTrees$Acc[combo_mtrTrees$mtrys==3 & combo_mtrTrees$ntrees==ntree]<-Acc3
  combo_mtrTrees$Acc[combo_mtrTrees$mtrys==4 & combo_mtrTrees$ntrees==ntree]<-Acc4
}
```

Comment: Hi Jack, you need to limit your post to **one question** at the time. Plus, make sure you are **not** asking for subjective solutions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Yes, it would be better to search over the interactions of parameters.
2. `nodesize` and `maxnodes` are usually left at default but there is no reason not to tune them. Personally I would leave `maxnodes` at default and perhaps tune `nodesize` - it can be seen as a regularization parameter. To get an idea of what values to try, check the default value in [`rf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/randomForest) these are 1 for classification and 5 for regression. So trying 1-10 would be an option.
3. when performing tuning in a loop like in your example it is advisable to use the same cross-validation folds always. You can create them using [`createFolds`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-84/topics/createDataPartition) prior calling the loop.
4. After tuning be sure to evaluate your results on an independent validation set or perform [nested cross validation](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/nested_resampling.html) where the inner loop would be used to tune parameters and the outer loop to estimate model performance. Since the results from just cross validation will be optimistically biased.
5. In most cases Accuracy is not a suitable metric to chose the best classification model. Especially in the case of imbalanced data sets. Read up on receiver operating characteristic auc, Cohen's kappa, Matthews correlation coefficient, balanced accuracy, F1 score, classification threshold tuning.
6. Here is an example on how to tune the `rf` parameters jointly. I will use the Sonar data set from `mlbench` package.

create predefined folds:

```
library(caret) 
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

set.seed(1234)
cv_folds <- createFolds(Sonar$Class, k = 5, returnTrain = TRUE)
```

create tune control:

```
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(1 : 10))

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                     number = 5,
                     search = 'grid',
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     savePredictions = "final",
                     index = cv_folds,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary) #in most cases a better summary for two class problems
```

define other parameters to tune. I will use just a few combinations to limit the train time of the example:

```
ntrees <- c(500, 1000)    
nodesize <- c(1, 5)

params <- expand.grid(ntrees = ntrees,
                      nodesize = nodesize)
```

train:

```
store_maxnode <- vector("list", nrow(params))
for(i in 1:nrow(params)){
  nodesize <- params[i,2]
  ntree <- params[i,1]
  set.seed(65)
  rf_model <- train(Class~.,
                       data = Sonar,
                       method = "rf",
                       importance=TRUE,
                       metric = "ROC",
                       tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
                       trControl = ctrl,
                       ntree = ntree,
                       nodesize = nodesize)
  store_maxnode[[i]] <- rf_model
  }
```

################### 26.02.2021.

In order to avoid generic model names - model1, model2 ... we can name the resulting list with the corresponding parameters:

```
names(store_maxnode) <- paste("ntrees:", params$ntrees,
                              "nodesize:", params$nodesize)
```

################### 26.02.2021.

combine results:

```
results_mtry <- resamples(store_maxnode)

summary(results_mtry)
```

output:

```
Call:
summary.resamples(object = results_mtry)

Models: ntrees: 500 nodesize: 1, ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 1, ntrees: 500 nodesize: 5, ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 5 
Number of resamples: 5 

ROC 
                              Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
ntrees: 500 nodesize: 1  0.9108696 0.9354067 0.9449761 0.9465758 0.9688995 0.9727273    0
ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 1 0.8847826 0.9473684 0.9569378 0.9474828 0.9665072 0.9818182    0
ntrees: 500 nodesize: 5  0.9163043 0.9377990 0.9569378 0.9481652 0.9593301 0.9704545    0
ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 5 0.9000000 0.9342105 0.9521531 0.9462321 0.9641148 0.9806818    0

Sens 
                              Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
ntrees: 500 nodesize: 1  0.9090909 0.9545455 0.9545455 0.9549407 0.9565217 1.0000000    0
ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 1 0.9090909 0.9130435 0.9545455 0.9371542 0.9545455 0.9545455    0
ntrees: 500 nodesize: 5  0.9090909 0.9545455 0.9545455 0.9458498 0.9545455 0.9565217    0
ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 5 0.9090909 0.9545455 0.9545455 0.9458498 0.9545455 0.9565217    0

Spec 
                         Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
ntrees: 500 nodesize: 1  0.65 0.6842105 0.7368421 0.7421053 0.7894737 0.8500000    0
ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 1 0.60 0.6842105 0.7894737 0.7631579 0.8421053 0.9000000    0
ntrees: 500 nodesize: 5  0.55 0.6842105 0.7894737 0.7331579 0.8000000 0.8421053    0
ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 5 0.60 0.6842105 0.7368421 0.7321053 0.7894737 0.8500000    0
```

To get the best mtry for each model:

```
lapply(store_maxnode, function(x) x$best)
#output
$`ntrees: 500 nodesize: 1`
  mtry
1    1

$`ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 1`
  mtry
2    2

$`ntrees: 500 nodesize: 5`
  mtry
1    1

$`ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 5`
  mtry
1    1
```

################### 26.02.2021.
or alternatively to get the best average performance for each model

```
lapply(store_maxnode, function(x) x$results[x$results$ROC == max(x$results$ROC),])
#output
$`ntrees: 500 nodesize: 1`
  mtry       ROC      Sens      Spec      ROCSD     SensSD    SpecSD
1    1 0.9465758 0.9549407 0.7421053 0.02541895 0.03215337 0.0802308

$`ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 1`
  mtry       ROC      Sens      Spec      ROCSD     SensSD    SpecSD
2    2 0.9474828 0.9371542 0.7631579 0.03728797 0.02385499 0.1209382

$`ntrees: 500 nodesize: 5`
  mtry       ROC      Sens      Spec      ROCSD     SensSD    SpecSD
1    1 0.9481652 0.9458498 0.7331579 0.02133659 0.02056666 0.1177407

$`ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 5`
  mtry       ROC      Sens      Spec      ROCSD     SensSD    SpecSD
1    1 0.9462321 0.9458498 0.7321053 0.03091747 0.02056666 0.0961229
```

From this toy example you see that the highest average (over the 5 folds) area under the ROC curve (ROC) is achieved with ntrees: 500, nodesize: 5 and mtry: 1 and that it is equal to 0.948.
###################

Alternatively you can use the default summary

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                         number = 5,
                         search = 'grid',
                         classProbs = TRUE,
                         savePredictions = "final",
                         index = cv_folds)
```

and define `metric = "Kappa"` in `train`

Comment: Above and beyond the question!

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic answer! Can you tell me how to see the best nodesize and ntrees? I tried `summary(resamples(nodesize))`. Also for clarification, are the four models representing the four training folds in this 5-fold cross validation?

Comment: Thanks so much for your edits!! Following up on this, I have observed that if you just pull out the best params through rf_model, (such as through `rf_model$finalModel$params`) it sometimes selects for a node__size and ntree that visually looking at your `lapply` from above doesn't actually give you the best ROC, but rather a middle one. I was always under the assumption if `metric=ROC` the `$finalModel` would always have the best parameters?

Comment: @PleaseHelp for the above example the prams in the `finalModel` match the params used in the `lapply` call: `lapply(store_maxnode, function(x) x$finalModel$param)`. If you have an example where they don't please post a new question.

Comment: @missuse  I am trying to do the same as OP. My questions is: once you have the best values for mtry/ntrees/nodesize, do I build a new model using randomForest with the parameters set to these optimal values? So I create a new Train/Test split, and run a random forest with the optimized hyperparameters

Comment: @JackArmstrong please help with above comment regarding running the final model with the best hyperparameters

Comment: @user2450223 you can just extract the best model from the created list object (`store_maxnode`) in the answer. Since caret already built the final model using all the train data based on best hyperparameters obtained during resampling. For instance: `model <- store_maxnode$ntrees: 500 nodesize: 5`; `predict(model, newdata)`

Comment: Once you get the hyperparameters, you can re-run a RF with the same train/test split with those hyperparameters explicitly. OR, R must have a built-in method to determine the best hyperparams, then extract those hyperparams as either variables or the entire model (which will store the hyperparams automatically). Then predict with that model object.

Comment: Thanks @JackArmstrong. I went with the first option - re-ran a RF with the optimized hyperparameters explicitly. I couldn't find where caret stores the optimised RF (I don't think it does)

Comment: Thank you @missuse, I explicitly built a RF with the best hyperparameters. I couldn't find where the best RF with the optimal hyperparameters is run during resampling. But your code was incredibly useful - thank you!

Comment: @user2450223 see documentation for [`caret::train`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-92/topics/train), the slot `finalModel` contains `A fit object using the best parameters`, you can use it directly with the associated predict function from an appropriate package, or you can use `caret::predict` on the caret output object directly. The latter is better if you performed some sort of preprocessing within resampling.